# Devops: Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file because it was not found

Tags: azure-devops, desktop-bridge, xaf

I am following [this blog on using the Desktop Bridge with XAF](http://blog.delegate.at/2018/04/15/how-to-use-the-desktop-bridge-to-create-an-appx-package-for-xaf.html)
The Win10 project runs on my machine.

However the build in devops has the error

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(4544,5): 
Error MSB3030: Could not copy the file "D:\a\1\s\MyApp.Win10\ModelAssembly.dll" because it was not found.
Process 'msbuild.exe' exited with code '1'.
```

This would be because ModelAssembly is prebuilt and the .dll is added to the project as an existing file.

How should I provide a the pre-build dll to devops?

ModelAssembly.dll is created by XAF when the Cli project is run.

Comment: looking at https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms.feed

Comment: http://blog.delegate.at/2016/02/26/nuget-packages-devexpress-components.html

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2016/06/28/creating-nuget-packages/